# Firebase query only documents I participate in

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to create simple one-to-one chat. I created structure like this:

[image]

My chat document id is:

```
const roomId = sender < reciever ? sender + reciever : reciever + sender
```

I can add to it but I have 0 clue how would I query only the ones that have my id in the id. Since I have no clue what is the reciever id at the point I query the documents. Should I create new collection under my user document that keeps reference of the chats? If so how would I then query only messages I am in?

I tried like this:

```
firebase.firestore().collection('chats').where('senderId', '==', currentUser.id)
```

but I have no idea who is sender and who is reciever at the time I query them so only one user can see the chats.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: you should store sender id and receiver id in the chat object

Comment: If you are interested, I have explained in one of my **[tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u3KwKQddPoo)** how you can structure such a database for a one-to-one chat app.

Comment: @SakshamGupta and then just query all the chat docents and use the where() clause?

Comment: @TarvoMäesepp yes exactly. query the chats wherever the user id matches sender id or receiver id

Comment: @SakshamGupta How do you know who is reciever and who is sender at the time I query the chats? I updated the question aswell.

Comment: You don't have to, just get all chats, then figure out who is sender on clientside